# Updating a row based on a column value in cassandra using hector api

Tags: cassandra

Can anyone help on how to update row with particular column values using the hector api for cassandra.

i.e equivalent of

UPDATE table_name SET value=" " where column_name=column_value;

Comment: Have you tried using Hector's `CqlQuery`?

Comment: in cql query we would need to hard code the parameters, is there a way to dynamically pass the required parameters something like a prepared statement?

Comment: I don't know if Hector supports prepared statements but CQL does. You should consider using the DataStax java driver, it is simpler when using CQL.

Answer (score 1):

Updates in Cassandra may only be done by primary key.

(More generally, I'd recommend using the native CQL driver at https://github.com/datastax/java-driver over the semi-obsolete Hector.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringSerializer ss = StringSerializer.get();
    String keyspaceName = "Test_Keyspace";
    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160"));
    Keyspace ksp = HFactory.createKeyspace(keyspaceName, cluster);
```

// UPDATE==============================

```
ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String> template = new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String>(ksp,"Standard1",ss,ss);

    ColumnFamilyUpdater<String, String> updater = template.createUpdater("jsmith");
    updater.setString("first", "Devid");

    ColumnFamilyUpdater<String, String> updater2 = template.createUpdater("ksmith");
    updater2.setString("first", "Kohli");
    updater2.setString("middle", "Virat");

    try {
        template.update(updater);
        template.update(updater2);

        RangeSlicesQuery<String, String, String> rangeSlicesQuery3 = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(ksp,ss,ss,ss);
        rangeSlicesQuery3.setColumnFamily("Standard1");
        rangeSlicesQuery3.setKeys("jsmith", "ksmith");
        rangeSlicesQuery3.setRange("jsmith", null, false, 4);
        QueryResult<OrderedRows<String, String, String>> result6 = rangeSlicesQuery3.execute();
    //  System.out.println(result6.get());
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        // do something ...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```